Quiero solo mostrar 5 resultados desde base de datos
Tengo este código en mi php


<span class="designation subcategoria"> @foreach($dl->subcategorias as $subcategoria)
<li class="designation subcategoria">{{ $subcategoria->description }}</li>@endforeach</span>



Lo que necesito es que la página solo muestre 5 resultados de los que se guardaron en la base de datos. Son subcategorías, y hay algunas entradas que tienen muchas subcategorías. Entonces, solo quiero mostrar 5 en la página principal.
No sé que puedo agregar para indicarle que solo muestre 5.

podes agregar un contador interno que corte el for.. podes usar un while con un contador.. podes usar un for que vaya contando.. podes a mano buscar las 5 posiciones que queres... formas hay muchas...

Hola, gracias por tu respuesta... no se como hacerlo :( El tema es el siguiente, las subcategorias se suben cuando se carga la ficha del profesional, si tiene muchas aparecen todas en la ficha que aparece en la home, y no se ve bien. Solo quiero que muestre 5. Después cuando se ingresa a la ficha, ahí si se muestran todas.

Desde la consulta en MySQL puedes limitar que te devuelva solo las últimas 5 categorías agregadas así por ejemplo:
SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE subcategorias = 111 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5

No sé si usas Laravel, o algún framework similar por la estructura de tu código. Si es así puedes utilizar un contador y un condicional, así por ejemplo:
    <span class="designation subcategoria">
    @php $counter = 0; @endphp
    @foreach($dl->subcategorias as $subcategoria)
        @if($counter < 5)
            <li class="designation subcategoria">{{ $subcategoria->description }}</li>
            @php $counter++; @endphp
        @else
            @break
        @endif
    @endforeach
    </span>


DjCrazy funciono a la  perfección, muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Use el último código, mi sitio usa Laravel. Gracias, por tu ayuda :)

puedes hacerlo asi:
eloquent:
$subcategoria->->skip(0)->take(5)->get();

aqui seleccionamos de la 0 a la 5
@foreach($dl->subcategorias as $subcategoria)
    // tu codigo

    @if($loop->iteration > 5)
        @break
    @endif
    
@endforeach

blade internamente trae un varible $loop
otros attributos de loop:

$loop->index: Devuelve el índice del elemento actual en el bucle
(inicia en 0).
$loop->iteration: Devuelve el número de iteración actual (inicia en
1).
$loop->remaining: Devuelve el número de iteraciones restantes en el
bucle, excluyendo la iteración actual.
$loop->count: Devuelve el número total de elementos en el bucle.
$loop->first: Devuelve true si es la primera iteración del bucle; de
lo contrario, devuelve false.
$loop->last: Devuelve true si es la última iteración del bucle; de
lo contrario, devuelve false.
$loop->even: Devuelve true si la iteración actual es par; de lo
contrario, devuelve false.
$loop->odd: Devuelve true si la iteración actual es impar; de lo
contrario, devuelve false.
$loop->depth: Devuelve el nivel de anidación del bucle (inicia en 1
para un bucle no anidado).
$loop->parent: Contiene la información del bucle padre si hay un
bucle anidado.

mas attributos en:
$loop blade
